# xtensor compile error when using xt::isnan to check for NANs in string xtensor

Tags: c++, xtensor

The following code attempts to check for NAN values in a 2-D string xtensor. The reason it's checking for NANs is that the xtensor is created from an sql query which can return NAN values.

```
xt::xtensor<std::string, 2> a =
{ {std::string("A1"), std::string("A2"), std::string("A3"), std::string("A4"), std::string("A5")},
  {std::string("B1"), std::string("B2"), std::string("B3"), std::string("B4"), std::string("B5")}}; 

auto nan_list = xt::isnan(a); // <- this line causes the compile error
```

The code gets the following compile error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2665   'fpclassify': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types  Experiment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h 413 
Message lnt-arithmetic-overflow A sub-expression may overflow before being assigned to a wider type.    Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\repos\Experiment\Experiment\cAntenna_file.cpp   430 
Message     could be 'int fpclassify(long double) noexcept' Experiment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h 298 
Message     or       'int fpclassify(double) noexcept'  Experiment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h 293 
Message     or       'int fpclassify(float) noexcept'   Experiment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h 288 
Warning C6031   Return value ignored: 'getchar'.    Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\repos\Experiment\Experiment\Experiment.cpp  220 
Warning C6031   Return value ignored: 'getchar'.    Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\repos\Experiment\Experiment\Experiment.cpp  232 
Message     see reference to class template instantiation 'xt::xconst_accessible<xt::xfunction<F,const xt::xtensor_container<xt::uvector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,2,xt::layout_type::row_major,xt::xtensor_expression_tag> &>>' being compiled  Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\xtensor\xfunction.hpp   179 
Message     see reference to class template instantiation 'xt::xcontainer_inner_types<D>' being compiled    Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\xtensor\xaccessible.hpp 35  
Message     see reference to class template instantiation 'xt::xfunction<F,const xt::xtensor_container<xt::uvector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>,2,xt::layout_type::row_major,xt::xtensor_expression_tag> &>' being compiled Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\repos\Experiment\Experiment\Experiment.cpp  1718    
Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan<T>(_Ty) noexcept' being compiled   Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\xtensor\xmath.hpp   345 
Message     see reference to function template instantiation 'bool xt::math::isnan_fun::operator ()<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>(const T &) const' being compiled   Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\xtensor\xfunction.hpp   145 
Warning C6054   String 'str' might not be zero-terminated.  Experiment  C:\Users\echrsro\source\repos\Experiment\Experiment\cAntenna_file.cpp   353 
Message     while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty)' Experiment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h 412
```

Comment: Please post the complete errors from Output pan. The scraps from Error List are almost useless.

Comment: Voting to close as a type: `xt::isnan` expects a numbers, but the `a` is an array of strings.

Comment: There is not much we can do for your here except stating what @273K stated. I think if the error is too vague you should consider submitting an issue in the library (though I'm not sure it this should be considered an actual issue, but that is at the library level to discuss).